# ordering the Xml

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a xml which is having empty spaces between and tags which dont have proper indentation .
How to reorder it..?

Output i want is XML doc which is properly indentd and no empty line inbetween

```
<Document>
    <another>
        <tag1>
            <content>a</content> <!-- might be other nested tags inside <content></content>-->
<content>b</content> <!--might be other nested tags inside <content></content>-->
            <content>c</content> <!--might be other nested tags inside <content></content>-->
        </tag1>

        <tag_b>
            <things>d</things> <!--might be other nested tags inside <things></things>-->
            <things>e</things> <!--might be other nested tags inside <things></things>-->

            <tag_C>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </tag_C>
        </tag_b>

        <tag_b>
<things>f</things> <!--might be other nested tags inside <things></things>-->
            <things>g</things> <!--might be other nested tags inside <things></things>-->

            <tag_C>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </tag_C>
        </tag_b>

        <tag_b>
<things>f</things> <!--might be other nested tags inside <things></things>-->
                     <things>g</things> <!--might be other nested tags inside <things></things>-->

            <tag_C>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </tag_C>
        </tag_b>
    </another>
```

Comment: Use `BeautifulSoup` to prettyprint it.

Comment: Indentation and empty lines do not matter to XML in any way.  Why are you worried about this?